# Force cells to be negative?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So, I have a spreadsheet that has a dropdown list to choose from cash, deposit/refund, check, etc. Then I have several columns that will tally both at the bottom and at the right. I need the cells of those columns to always be negative if the "deposit/refund" option is selected, but still allow them to type whatever value into the cell.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is a work around acceptable? E.g. numbers in column B, and the guaranteed negative version of those in another column (with `=if(B1<0, B1, -B1)`). You could nest that with an extra if to see if "deposit/refund"was selected for the relevant row.

If that is not the solution, then please add what you already tried.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/782956/how-to-automatically-make-all-entered-numbers-in-a-row-negative-using-excel

Answer (score 1):

This formula will make all of the values in the range **A1:A8** positive and then sum them up. Using the negative sign at the end to give negative deposit/refund

```
=-SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A1:A8))
```

for your example you might choose to use something like the following, with the filter in cell **B1**:

```
=IF(B1="deposit/refund",-1,1)*SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A1:A8))
```